# Disabling zooming when scrolling over leaflet map in R

Tags: r, r-leaflet

i want to disable zooming on my leaflet map in R while having the mouse hover over it.

I tried the `suspendScroll(hoverToWake = FALSE)` function from the `leaflet.extras` package as well as `leaflet(options = leafletOptions(scrollWheelZoom = FALSE))`, but both not working.

```
leaflet(width = "100%") %>%
  setView(0, 0, 1) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  suspendScroll(hoverToWake = FALSE)
```

The map is still zooming in and out when i hover the mouse over it and start scrolling. Am i the only one having this problem? My R Version is 3.6.1

Comment: unfotunatly not, because it is only working like this when using leaflet javascript, i am using leaflet in R

Answer (score 3):

If you want to disable all zooming, you can set the `minZoom` and `maxZoom` to the same number as the `zoom` in `setView`. Like this reproducible example:

```
map <- leaflet(options = leafletOptions(minZoom = 10, maxZoom = 10)) %>% 
addTiles() %>% 
setView(lng = 7.35, lat = 50.05, zoom = 10)
map
```